# Auth::login() not working properly laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I'm trying to setup 'Login with facebook' using laravel socialite. When I try to login, it gets a successful callback from the facebook, I'm storing the data fetched into the database and try to redirect to home page. While doing so, I am redirected back to the login page and never reaching the homepage.

While debugging the error I found that my Auth::login($user) is not working properly.

Here is the code-

**AuthController.php**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Laravel\Socialite\Two\InvalidStateException;
use Auth;
use Socialite;
use App\User;

public function redirectToProvider($provider)
{
    return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
    $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
    // dd($user);
    $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user, $provider);
    // dd($authUser);
    if(Auth::login($authUser, true)){            // here is the error
      return redirect($this->redirectTo);
    }
    else{
      return 'Login not done';                 //this prints out to the screen
    }
}

public function findOrCreateUser($user, $provider)
 {
     $authUser = User::where('id', $user->id)->first();
     if ($authUser) {
         return $authUser;
     }
     return User::create([
         'name'     => $user->name,
         'email'    => $user->email,
         'avatar'    => $user->avatar,
         'password'    => bcrypt('password'),
         'provider' => $provider,
         'id' => $user->id
     ]);
 }
```

Do let me know what am I doing wrong.

This is what I'm getting while dd($authUser)

[image]

Comment: Does `Auth::login` return something? (From the first peek at the auth docs I could not see that there is a return value)

Comment: it returns null @Roland Starke

Comment: So an if else around it is useless. (Does not tell you if the login worked or not). You could just remove the if else and always redirect somewhere.

Comment: but when I do dd($authUser), it does return an array

Comment: redirecting directly won't serve the purpose of authenticating the user.

Comment: You would redirect after calling `Auth::login`..... Doesn't laravel handle unsuccessful logins for you? .... Idk anyway good luck.

Comment: It does. But I want to log the user in, which isn't happening right now. else statement is just a part of debugging.

Comment: shouldn't `dd($authUser)` be a model?

Comment: I have added the result of dd($authUser) in the question @RolandStarke

Comment: Check this part: `if(Auth::login($authUser, true)){dd(Auth::user())}`.

Comment: since it doesn't validates the if condition, it won't run `dd(Auth::user())` @Tpojka

Comment: if I run it without the if condition, it shows null @Tpojka

Comment: That's the problem: `Auth::login($authUser, true)` doesn't work. If Auth::login($user) worked, you'd have authenticated user.

Comment: I know that. But I don't know why isn't that working. @Tpojka

Comment: Shouldn't be critical case, but, try with absolute full class namespace instead of facade. I.e. `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`

Comment: Did you try `\Auth::loginUsingId($authUser->id);` ?

Comment: Do you use `users.id` column as the foreign ID or the primary key of your table? This seems a bit confusing. I would use a different column for remote ID's. You might not be saving the user at all.

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/laravel-social-authentication-with-socialite

Comment: yes I did tried `\Auth::loginUsingId($authUser->id);`, but no use @TahaPaksu

Comment: It is getting saved in the database though. @TahaPaksu

Comment: You might be doing it wrong. You shouldn't save that to the id variable. Follow the tutorial I've posted.

Comment: I didn't got the solution of this problem so I installed laravel 5.6 and socialite 3.0 and it is working fine now. I would like to know the solution of this problem though, because I know the update must have complicated the things. @TahaPaksu

Comment: Still, using another column instead of ID is better because you might need non unique values when there's a clash of ID's between two different providers. Might happen in a populated system.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are grabbing user details and saving them to your database you in order to login you need to use attempt and passing the details that you get from $authUser variable, but you need a way to get the password since the attempt convert the password string to the hash in order to login the user

```
$authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user, $provider);
  $credentials = $request->only($authUser->email, 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my end, I just resolved it by making the `domain` null in my session.php. I dont know if this is the correct answer but I can now redirect to my homepage after logging in with google. Maybe if you deploy this to production you will change the domain thing to the actual url.

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
    |
    */

    'secure' => false,
```

Answer (score 0):

`Auth::login()` return void. use

```
Auth::login($authUser, true);

if(Auth::check()){
  return redirect($this->redirectTo);
}
else{
  return 'Login not done';
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you should use `auth()->login($user);` function after create user to add user to auth

Comment: Incorrect. Both `Auth::login($user)` as `auth()->login($user);` are correct.

Comment: if(\Auth::check()){} try this

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - is there any good reason to use your code, and explicitly not the other?